# Evaluating the integral of $1+z+1/\tan z$ over a circle

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I am a beginner and I want to learn how to solve these kind of integrals:

$$\int_{|z|= \pi/4}\left(1+z+\frac{1}{\tan z}\right)\,dz$$

So should I divide it in three integrals, calculate each integral and use the residue theorem?

Comment: Yes, do what you said and you will be happy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split into two, rather than three. Since $1+z$ is holomorphic everywhere, its integral over a closed contour is zero. This leaves you just with the 
$1/\tan z $. I recommend writing it as $\frac{\cos z}{\sin z}$ and computing the residue at a pole $a$ as 
$$
\frac{\cos z}{(\sin z)'}\bigg|_{z=a}
$$

Comment: Sorry if I make a mistake here. But is it simply Res z = a g(z)/h'(z) where g(z) = cos(z) and h'(z) = (sin(z))' so cos(a)/cos(a) = 1 ? And what if say for example the final result was (if assumed the above is correct) cos(a)/a+cos(a), can i simply write that or do I have to find a somehow? Thank you very much.

Comment: I wrote "a" in my answer, but when you do the exercise, you will find exactly what the poles are. There is just one.